# Is it possible to run a recipe in parallel with others in chef with some hack?

Tags: python, chef-infra

I have a chef recipe say A which contains three recipes B, C and D. Now i what is to run D in parallel wrt sequential execution of B and C. One hack i know is write is to write logic of B, C and D in python(B.py, C.py and D.py) and execute them in parallel( All.py ) in some script and make a consolidated recipe that calls All.py. But the code is too large to convert. Is there any hack to run recipes in parallel in chef using the same recipes?

Answer (score 1):

No, Chef does not support concurrent execution in the general case. Chef-provisioning specifically supports concurrent handling for VM creation but that's a special case.

Comment: can you elaborate on cuncurrent handling for VM creation; because my work is on VM creation itself

Comment: Are you using chef-provisioning? If so, look at the docs for `machine_batch`

Comment: A draft outline of the feature can be found here: https://chef.github.io/chef-rfc/rfc044-in_parallel.html

Comment: @ives That will never get implemented (probably), as you can see in the status https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc044-in_parallel.md